# NSFetchRequest with sort descriptors for recursive CoreData Entity relationship

Tags: recursion, relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have got a simple CoreData entity "MyEntity" with a recursive relationship:
[image: MyEntity definition]

(The relation is a one-to-one relation in this case)

Imagine I had created 5 objects of this entity:

```
ObjectA -> ObjectB -> ObjectC -> ObjectD -> ObjectE
```

(`ObjectB` is the child of `ObjectA` and so on)

I would like to create a NSFetchRequest with NSSortDescriptors which return the objects in the correct order (from root to last child):

```
ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC
ObjectD
ObjectE
```

Is this possible?
(My specific problem is somewhat more complex, but I think I can get it done if I got this simple one solved)

Comment: Nobody? I know, this could be a hard one...

Answer (score 0):

Why bother, just fetch the parent object and then get it's child and the child's child from the property (relationship) directly.  If you need them in an array then use a while loop to traverse the hierarchy until child = nil.

Comment: Yes, I did that already, but now it's n fetch requests instead of 1. With >10000 entries wouldn't that be a performance killer?

Comment: Facing a similar problem. What if I want to use the result in an NSFetchedResultsController? The number of entries could change while showing it in a table view. Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that question is out of date, but came up with idea for those, who will stumble upon later

You can use one fetch request with predicate staiting that parent must be nil. After that you don't need no more fetch requests. You just get child from this one (or more, if that possible), object. Then, you get child from this new object (child of original object). And go on, while you have child to get